# Array Index is "Out of Bounds". But I can't see what's wrong

Tags: java

My IDE (TextPad) is giving me this error:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9

I looked at the array on line 38  and can't see what the problem is. changing the array would totally screw up the program.

```
   import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;


public class TicTacToeGame implements ActionListener {
    /*Define Buttons, Variables Etc*/
      int[][] winCombinations = new int[][] {
                    {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, //horizontal wins
                    {1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, {3, 6, 9}, //virticle wins
                    {1, 5, 9}, {3, 5, 7}
                };//diagonal wins

     JFrame window = new JFrame("Tic-Tac-Toe Game");
     JButton btn[] = new JButton[9];
     int count = 0;
     JLabel lblTitle = new JLabel("Tic Tac Toe Game");
     JLabel lblBlank = new JLabel(" ");
     String letter = "";
     boolean win = false;





    public TicTacToeGame(){
    /*Creates Window*/
    window.setSize(400,300);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));


    /*Adds Buttons To The Window& adds ActionListener to them*/
    for(int i = 1; i<=9; i++){
            btn[i] = new JButton();
            window.add(btn[i]);
            btn[i].addActionListener(this);
        }


    /*Make The Window Visible*/
    window.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {


      /*Write the letter to the button and deactivate it*/
            for(int i = 1; i<= 9; i++){
                if(a.getSource() == btn[i]){
                    btn[i].setText("X");
                    btn[i].setEnabled(false);
                }
            }

            count++;
            AI();

        }


          public void AI(){
              count++;
              if(btn[1].getText().equals("O") && btn[2].getText().equals("O") && btn[3].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[3].setText("O");
                  btn[3].setEnabled(false);
              } else if(btn[4].getText().equals("O") && btn[5].getText().equals("O") && btn[6].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[6].setText("O");
                  btn[6].setEnabled(false);
              } else if(btn[7].getText().equals("O") && btn[8].getText().equals("O") && btn[9].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[9].setText("O");
                  btn[9].setEnabled(false);
              }

              else if(btn[2].getText().equals("O") && btn[3].getText().equals("O") && btn[1].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[1].setText("O");
                  btn[1].setEnabled(false);
              } else if(btn[5].getText().equals("O") && btn[6].getText().equals("O") && btn[4].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[4].setText("O");
                  btn[4].setEnabled(false);
              } else if(btn[8].getText().equals("O") && btn[9].getText().equals("O") && btn[7].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[7].setText("O");
                  btn[7].setEnabled(false);
              }

              else if(btn[1].getText().equals("O") && btn[3].getText().equals("O") && btn[2].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[2].setText("O");
                  btn[2].setEnabled(false);
              } else if(btn[4].getText().equals("O") && btn[6].getText().equals("O") && btn[5].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[5].setText("O");
                  btn[5].setEnabled(false);
              } else if(btn[7].getText().equals("O") && btn[9].getText().equals("O") && btn[8].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[8].setText("O");
                  btn[8].setEnabled(false);
              }

              else if(btn[1].getText().equals("O") && btn[4].getText().equals("O") && btn[7].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[7].setText("O");
                  btn[7].setEnabled(false);
              } else if(btn[2].getText().equals("O") && btn[5].getText().equals("O") && btn[8].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[4].setText("O");
                  btn[4].setEnabled(false);
              } else if(btn[3].getText().equals("O") && btn[6].getText().equals("O") && btn[9].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[9].setText("O");
                  btn[9].setEnabled(false);
              }

              else if(btn[4].getText().equals("O") && btn[7].getText().equals("O") && btn[1].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[1].setText("O");
                  btn[1].setEnabled(false);
              } else if(btn[5].getText().equals("O") && btn[8].getText().equals("O") && btn[2].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[2].setText("O");
                  btn[2].setEnabled(false);
              } else if(btn[6].getText().equals("O") && btn[9].getText().equals("O") && btn[3].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[3].setText("O");
                  btn[3].setEnabled(false);
              }

              else if(btn[1].getText().equals("O") && btn[7].getText().equals("O") && btn[4].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[4].setText("O");
                  btn[4].setEnabled(false);
              } else if(btn[2].getText().equals("O") && btn[8].getText().equals("O") && btn[5].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[5].setText("O");
                  btn[5].setEnabled(false);
              } else if(btn[3].getText().equals("O") && btn[9].getText().equals("O") && btn[6].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[6].setText("O");
                  btn[6].setEnabled(false);
              }

              else if(btn[1].getText().equals("O") && btn[5].getText().equals("O") && btn[9].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[9].setText("O");
                  btn[9].setEnabled(false);
              } else if(btn[5].getText().equals("O") && btn[9].getText().equals("O") && btn[1].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[1].setText("O");
                  btn[1].setEnabled(false);
              } else if(btn[1].getText().equals("O") && btn[9].getText().equals("O") && btn[5].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[5].setText("O");
                  btn[5].setEnabled(false);
              }

              else if(btn[3].getText().equals("O") && btn[5].getText().equals("O") && btn[7].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[7].setText("O");
                  btn[7].setEnabled(false);
              } else if(btn[7].getText().equals("O") && btn[5].getText().equals("O") && btn[3].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[3].setText("O");
                  btn[3].setEnabled(false);
              } else if(btn[7].getText().equals("O") && btn[3].getText().equals("O") && btn[5].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[5].setText("O");
                  btn[5].setEnabled(false);
              }

              else if(btn[1].getText().equals("X") && btn[2].getText().equals("X") && btn[3].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[3].setText("O");
                  btn[3].setEnabled(false);
              } else if(btn[4].getText().equals("X") && btn[5].getText().equals("X") && btn[6].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[6].setText("O");
                  btn[6].setEnabled(false);
              } else if(btn[7].getText().equals("X") && btn[8].getText().equals("X") && btn[9].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[9].setText("O");
                  btn[9].setEnabled(false);
              }

              else if(btn[2].getText().equals("X") && btn[3].getText().equals("X") && btn[1].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[1].setText("O");
                  btn[1].setEnabled(false);
              } else if(btn[5].getText().equals("X") && btn[6].getText().equals("X") && btn[4].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[4].setText("O");
                  btn[4].setEnabled(false);
              } else if(btn[8].getText().equals("X") && btn[9].getText().equals("X") && btn[7].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[7].setText("O");
                  btn[7].setEnabled(false);
              }

              else if(btn[1].getText().equals("X") && btn[3].getText().equals("X") && btn[2].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[2].setText("O");
                  btn[2].setEnabled(false);
              } else if(btn[4].getText().equals("X") && btn[6].getText().equals("X") && btn[5].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[5].setText("O");
                  btn[5].setEnabled(false);
              } else if(btn[7].getText().equals("X") && btn[9].getText().equals("X") && btn[8].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[8].setText("O");
                  btn[8].setEnabled(false);
              }

              else if(btn[1].getText().equals("X") && btn[4].getText().equals("X") && btn[7].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[7].setText("O");
                  btn[7].setEnabled(false);
              } else if(btn[2].getText().equals("X") && btn[5].getText().equals("X") && btn[8].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[8].setText("O");
                  btn[8].setEnabled(false);
              } else if(btn[3].getText().equals("X") && btn[6].getText().equals("X") && btn[9].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[9].setText("O");
                  btn[9].setEnabled(false);
              }

              else if(btn[4].getText().equals("X") && btn[7].getText().equals("X") && btn[1].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[1].setText("O");
                  btn[1].setEnabled(false);
              } else if(btn[5].getText().equals("X") && btn[8].getText().equals("X") && btn[2].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[2].setText("O");
                  btn[2].setEnabled(false);
              } else if(btn[6].getText().equals("X") && btn[9].getText().equals("X") && btn[3].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[3].setText("O");
                  btn[3].setEnabled(false);
              }

              else if(btn[1].getText().equals("X") && btn[7].getText().equals("X") && btn[4].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[4].setText("O");
                  btn[4].setEnabled(false);
              } else if(btn[2].getText().equals("X") && btn[8].getText().equals("X") && btn[5].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[5].setText("O");
                  btn[5].setEnabled(false);
              } else if(btn[3].getText().equals("X") && btn[9].getText().equals("X") && btn[6].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[6].setText("O");
                  btn[6].setEnabled(false);
              }

              else if(btn[1].getText().equals("X") && btn[5].getText().equals("X") && btn[9].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[9].setText("O");
                  btn[9].setEnabled(false);
              } else if(btn[5].getText().equals("X") && btn[9].getText().equals("X") && btn[1].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[1].setText("O");
                  btn[1].setEnabled(false);
              } else if(btn[1].getText().equals("X") && btn[9].getText().equals("X") && btn[5].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[5].setText("O");
                  btn[5].setEnabled(false);
              }

              else if(btn[3].getText().equals("X") && btn[5].getText().equals("X") && btn[7].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[7].setText("O");
                  btn[7].setEnabled(false);
              } else if(btn[7].getText().equals("X") && btn[5].getText().equals("X") && btn[3].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[3].setText("O");
                  btn[3].setEnabled(false);
              } else if(btn[7].getText().equals("X") && btn[3].getText().equals("X") && btn[5].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[5].setText("O");
                  btn[5].setEnabled(false);
              }

              else if(btn[1].getText().equals("X") && btn[5].getText().equals("O") && btn[9].getText().equals("X")) {
                  btn[6].setText("O");
                  btn[6].setEnabled(false);
              }

              else if(btn[3].getText().equals("X") && btn[5].getText().equals("O") && btn[7].getText().equals("X")) {
                  btn[4].setText("O");
                  btn[4].setEnabled(false);
              }

              else if(btn[5].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[5].setText("O");
                  btn[5].setEnabled(false);
              }

              else if(btn[1].getText().equals("")){
                  btn[1].setText("O");
                  btn[1].setEnabled(false);
              }
              else {
                  if(count >= 9)
                      checkWin();
                  else
                      RandomMove();
              }

              checkWin();

          }

          public void RandomMove(){
              Random x = new Random();
              int y = 1 + x.nextInt(9);
              if(btn[y].getText().equals("O") || btn[y].getText().equals("X") ){
                  RandomMove();
              } else {
                  btn[y].setText("O");
                  btn[y].setEnabled(false);
              }
          }

 public void checkWin(){

        /*Determine who won*/
        for(int i=0; i<=7; i++){
            if( btn[winCombinations[i][0]].getText().equals(btn[winCombinations[i][1]].getText()) &&
                btn[winCombinations[i][1]].getText().equals(btn[winCombinations[i][2]].getText()) &&
                !btn[winCombinations[i][0]].getText().equals("")) {
                win = true;
            }
        }

        if(count % 2 == 0)
            letter = "<font color='blue'>O";
        else
            letter = "<font color='red'>X";



        /*Shows Win & Tie Status Message*/
        if(win == true){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, letter + " WINS!</font></html>");
        } else if(count == 9 && win == false){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tie Game!");
        }

}
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new TicTacToeGame();
    }
}
```

Comment: eh.. that's huge.. can you show us the exact line where the stacktrace points? (don't make us count)

Comment: @Bozho: Line 38, as per the description. Fortunately that does appear to be the line in question :)

Comment: yeah, but I had to count :) which slowed my answer :)

Comment: That is some ugly code in the `AI` method.  Is there no way to make this smaller and more comprehensible?  All those magic numbers make it a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: I'm a n00b and don't really know a better way of doing it. When I figure it out, I'll make changes. I agree, very ugly. Best I could do.

Answer (score 12):

You're treating the array as if it were 1-based... arrays are always 0-based in Java. So this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
```

should be this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
```

You'll need to adjust the rest of your program to account for this too. (You *could* just create the array one bigger and ignore element 0, but that would be pretty non-idiomatic.)

Comment: Jon Skeet, guru of SO, noble helper of beginners... ;)

Comment: thanks, i'm taking four different languages concurrently at my college. So the rules become a bit blurry at times.